# CKEditor - Use Advanced Content Filter rule to specify values

Tags: filter, ckeditor, rules

It seems that some plugins of CKEditor specify values of properties. For example, the **left-to-right** plugin has the following rule:

```
{
  "styles":null,
  "requiredStyles":null,
  "classes":null,
  "requiredClasses":null,
  "attributes":{
    "dir":"ltr"
  },
  "requiredAttributes":{
    "dir":true
  },
  "elements":{
    "span":true
  },
  "featureName":"styles",
  "propertiesOnly":false,
  "match":null
},
```

How can I specify values with string format rules?
Something like `span[!dir=ltr]`.

Comment: You want these rules back in string format, am I right?

Comment: You're right! And I don't know how to translate `"attributes":{"dir":"ltr"}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. String format doesn't allow such definition. You can specify `span[!dir]` so all spans require `dir` attribute and nothing else. With object definition you can do more, e.g. use functions:

```
...
'ul, li: true,
'$0': {
    match: function( el ) {
        return el.name == 'b';
    },
    propertiesOnly: true,
    attributes: 'dir'
}
'$1': {
...
```

Why do you persist to use string format? You can use objects and store it as JSON.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `match` function validates whether this rule should be applied to given element. So you can check there the value of `el.attributes.dir` and return `false` to skip element which has a wrong value. If it is the only rule allowing `dir` attribute, then it will be removed.

Comment: Thank you. Are there docs talking about that? What is `$0`? I can store it as Object format. I though the Object has the same ability as the string format.